# Concurrency in Java: synchronized static methods

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I want to understand how locking is done on static methods in Java.

let's say I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
    private static int bar = 0;
    public static synchronized void inc() { bar++; }
    public synchronized int get() { return bar; }
```

It's my understanding that when I call `f.get()`, the thread acquires the lock on the object `f` and when I do `Foo.inc()` the thread acquires the lock on the class `Foo`.

My question is how are the two calls synchronized in respect to each other?
Is calling a static method also acquires a lock on all instantiations, or the other way around (which seems more reasonable)?

---

**EDIT:**

My question isn't exactly how `static synchronized` works, but how does static and non-static methods are synchronized with each other.
i.e., I don't want two threads to simultaneously call both `f.get()` and `Foo.inc()`, but these methods acquire different locks. My question is how is this preventable and is it prevented in the above code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Static and instance `synchronized` methods are not related to each other, therefore you need to apply some additional synchronization between them, like this:

```
class Foo {
    private static int bar = 0;
    public static synchronized void inc() { bar++; }
    public synchronized int get() { 
        synchronized (Foo.class) { // Synchronizes with static synchronized methods
            return bar; 
        }
    }
}
```

(though in this case leaving `synchronized` on `get()` doesn't make sense, since it doesn't do anything that requires synchronization on instance).

Beware of deadlocks - since this code aquires multiple locks, it should do it in consistent order, i.e. other synchronized static methods shouldn't try to acquire instance locks.

Also note that this particular task can be solved without synchronization at all, using atomic fields:

```
class Foo {
    private static AtomicInteger bar = new AtomicInteger(0);
    public static void inc() { bar.getAndIncrement(); }
    public int get() { return bar.get(); }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A synchronized static method is effectively equivalent to:

```
public static void foo() {
    synchronized (ClassName.class) {
        // Body
    }
}
```

In other words, it locks on the `Class` object associated with the class declaring the method.

From [section 8.4.3.6 of the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.3.6):

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes. For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used. For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object for which the method was invoked) is used.

Answer (score 3):

If you read http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html.

It will tell you:

> You might wonder what happens when a
>   static synchronized method is invoked,
>   since a static method is associated
>   with a class, not an object. In this
>   case, the thread acquires the
>   intrinsic lock for the Class object
>   associated with the class. Thus access
>   to class's static fields is controlled
>   by a lock that's distinct from the
>   lock for any instance of the class.

which tells you all you need to know.

Answer (score 2):

Neither, the non-static synchronized call does not acquire a lock on the class itself. (And the static synchronized block does not lock any object instantiated from that class.)

In other words the calls `f.get()` (locks `f`) and `Foo.inc()` (locks the class `Foo`) can run concurrently. They are not "synchronized".

You could use a different pattern (singleton), or make all the methods static.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment - the static synchronized method does acquire a lock on the `Class`, but not on any object created with it (`Foo a  = new Foo();` - `Foo.inc()` locks the thing returned by  `a.getClass()`, but not `a`). Or I am wrong?

Comment: `Foo.inc()` or `new Foo().inc()` will both lock with respect to each other, which would also lock against `Foo.dec()` if it was declared `static`.

Comment: Yes, because they both lock the class. And neither of those lock an object instantiated from that class like the `a` in my previous comment or your unnamed new Foo object. I don't see what is wrong in the wording in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Static` locks are attached to the `class` definition and thus is shared between all instances of that *class*.

Synchronization of `none static` methods only apply to the current instance of the class (the lock is on the class *instance*, e.g., `this`). In your example you have two different locks with no interrelation.

> I don't want two threads to simultaneously call both f.get() and Foo.inc(), but these methods acquire different locks. My question is how is this preventable and is it prevented in the above code

You *must* share a lock to be able to arbitrate access to both `f.get` and `Foo.inc()`. You can do this either by sharing the same static lock or by the same instance lock.

Answer (score 0):

These two calls do not synchronize in respect to each other.
It is as you said, a caller of `f.get()` acquires the lock of `f` object and caller of `Foo.inc()` acquires `Foo.class` object's one. So the synchronization rules are the same as if instead of static call you called an instance synchronized method with another object.