# static synchronised method vs non static synchronised method

Tags: java, static, synchronized, non-static

I have a class

```
class Foo{

    static synchronized get(){}
    synchronized() getMore(){}
}
```

I have 2 objects `Foo.get()` and `f.getMore()` running in 2 different threads t1 and t2. i had a dobuts whether when thread t1 had got a lock on the class can thread t2 access the method getMore or would t2 be prevented from getting the access and the lock to the method since the class object is locked by t1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concurrency in Java: synchronized static methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443297/concurrency-in-java-synchronized-static-methods)

Answer (score 3):

The static method will synchronise on the `Class` object as opposed to the instance object. You have 2 locks operating on 2 different objects. In your scenario above there will be no blocking behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Static Synchronized ---> Class Level Locking (Class level scope)

it is similar to

```
synchronized(SomeClass.class){
 //some code
}
```

Simple Synchronized ---> Instance level locking

Example:

```
class Foo{

     public static synchronized void bar(){
         //Only one thread would be able to call this at a time  
     }

     public synchronized void bazz(){
         //One thread at a time ----- If same instance of Foo
         //Multiple threads at a time ---- If different instances of Foo class
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`synchonized` locks an object and a `static synchronized` locks the object which represents the class.

t1 and t2 can call these methods concurrently except they cannot both be in the `static synchronized` method unless all but one thread is `wait()`ing.

Note: t1 and t2 can call `getMore()` at the same time for different objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `synchonized static method` will aquire the lock Of java.lang.Class object which is assosiated on behalf of Foo class.

The `synchonized instance method` will aquire the lock of Actual object.